# The most performant way to query against three collections, sort them and limit?

Tags: mongodb, database

I am in need of querying against 3 different collections.

Then I need to sort the collection results (each based on different field and order but every time a DateTime value), and then finally limit the number of results I want (10 in my case).

Currently I'm just doing three separate queries and limiting each by 10, then manually sorting based on the date times they have. Then I finally limit to 10 myself.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What are those collections? What do the queries look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mongodb is no relational database where you can join multiple tables within one query, no. I'm not even sure if you could do such kind of sorting (taking each field equal on the order precedence) for relational DBMS.

What you're doing already sounds really good. You could possibly improve your sorting of these 3 results. Aborting early to iterate over one or more collections if no further element can be within the overal top 10. You could modify your queries accordingly to only return documents for the other two collections, whose date is lower than the last one (10th) of the first queried collection. But maybe you did this already...

While talking about performance you may consider to add indexes on these datetime fields used for your query to keep the fields presorted in memory.